# How to fill the form with angular 2 using dynamic data from child component?

Tags: angular

I have the following DOM structure:
The app component has

```
<app-form-component></app-form-component>
```

And the form component has the following html snippet:

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
......
</form>
<app-form-detail></app-form-detail>
```

Now for this child detail component `app-form-detail`, whenever there is a form submit it creates a detail. In every detail there is an `edit` button.

Its possible to send the data from `app-form-component` to `app-form-detail` component. Now I have to send the data to fill in the form when I click on edit button from child component.

Comment: I tried with @Output event emitter, the problem here is that event should be placed inside form component as `<app-form-component (formEvent)="eventData($event)"></app-form-component>` which is not working. 
Because this is placed in <app-component></app-component>

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. check out 
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction for component interaction.

Make these changes it works..!!

In form.component.html

```
<app-form-detail [formEvent]="formEventSubject.asObservable(data)" (formEmitEvent)="editedDetails($event)"></app-form-detail>
```

In form.component.ts

```
editedDetails(data){
    console.log(data)
  }
```

In form-detail.component.ts

```
 @Output() formEmitEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();
  editForm(data) {
    this.formService.setData(data);
    this.formEmitEvent.emit(data)
  }
```

Make desired changes in editedDetails method in form.component.ts for your expected result